# Cant change executable bit

Tags: executable

I have written an c++ program ,but cant run it because the executable bit is not on yes.
 So I wanted to change it ,but it only changes it for a second and then swiches back.

Comment: If you have written a C program, you need to compile it using `gcc` or something before running it. If you then need to make it executable, run `chmod +X /PATH/TO/FILE` to make it executable (Another way is to open the file's properties window, and click yes to 'Allow executing the file as a program').  Then you should be able to run in it terminal by running `/PATH/TO/FILE`.

Comment: alrady compiled ,but if i do chmod +X ... the executable bit is still off (by the way ,i know how to change ,the problem is if i mark allow  executing the file as programm it marks it for about a half second and than swiches back.

Comment: You need to run it as root - `sudo chmod +x` (a little X by the way).

Comment: hmm..when in my home folder, sudo is never needed with chmod. Also if I compile a c-source with gcc, the resulting binary always has the executable bit set automagically. Something fishy is going on here.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rey7mircX1k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant change executable bit on fat systems.